# HttpListeners and ports

Tags: c#, .net, exception, httplistener

I am creating an HttpListener by attempting to grab a random port that is open (or one that is not in IpGlobalProperties.GetActiveTcpConnections()). The issue I am running into is that after a while of making these connections and disposing them I am getting this error : `No more memory is available for security information updates`
Is there any way to resolve this or is there a proper way of getting rid of HttpListeners. I am just calling listener.Close().

Here is the method used to create the listeners :

```
private HttpListener CreateListener()
        {
            HttpListener httpListener;
            DateTime timeout = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(30);
            bool foundPort = false;
            do
            {
                httpListener = new HttpListener();
                Port = GetAvailablePort();
                string uriPref = string.Format("http://{0}:{1}/", Environment.MachineName.ToLower(), Port);
                httpListener.Prefixes.Add(uriPref);
                try
                {
                    httpListener.Start();
                    foundPort = true;
                    break;
                }
                catch
                {
                    httpListener.Close();
                    FailedPorts.Add(Port);
                }
            } while (DateTime.Now < timeout);
```

```
        if (!foundPort)
            throw new NoAvailablePortException();

        return httpListener;
    }
```

Comment: For some reason it seems that the HttpListener is not properly disposing of the prefixes that get added, for instance if I start a prefix http://test/20000 and then close that listener and then reattempt to open the same prefix sometime later it tells me it's already registered. I'm betting that if I can unregister it then I can resolve this problem but removing prefixes from the list of prefixes doesn't seem to do it any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the hackish way to force HttpListener to unregister all your Prefixes associated with that httpListener (this uses some of my custom reflection libraries but the basic idea is the same)

```
private void StopListening()
{
    Reflection.ReflectionHelper.InvokeMethod(httpListener, "RemoveAll", new object[] {false});
    httpListener.Close();
    pendingRequestQueue.Clear(); //this is something we use but just in case you have some requests clear them
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried calling listener.Stop() before Close()?

Another thing to try is to wrap your code in a `using() {}` block to make sure your object is disposed properly.

Finally, what are you doing with the listener (a code snippet might help)?  Are you leaving any streams open?

Comment: I'm creating an HttpListener to communicate with a background script in Chrome. I do call stop before close (can't really use a using block since I need the HttpListener to persist until I'm done with it, which might take a while)

Comment: Are you instantiating/opening these listeners from within separate threads, or within a loop on the main executing thread?  Manually calling .Dispose() might not be a bad idea as well.

Comment: I don't think you can manually call Dispose on an HttpListener. Also they are all on the same thread. I'll keep looking to see if I've made any obvious errors but so far I see none. Again the only situation this happens is when opening and closing many (in the case where some ports are being used)

Comment: Code sample(s) might help here.

Comment: Do you have a using(){} block around the call to CreateListener, i.e. `using(listener = CreateListener()) {}` ?  Also, which line is throwing the exception - I assume `httpListener.Start();`?

Comment: Yes the Start() method throws an exception when the port is blocked. This isn't in a using block but when I am finished with the listener I do dispose of it, is there a limit to the total number of HttpListeners a process can create in one run? Eventually when creating a listener this just loops for the timeout and then if I debug it shows that No more memory for security information updates as the exception being thrown in the Start() method.

Comment: @JesusRamos `((IDisposable)listener).Dispose();`  It's hidden for a few reasons, one being that you're supposed to use a `using` block.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the failed prefix before adding a new one, which is a lot simpler then Jesus Ramos proposed.

```
httpListener.Prefixes.Remove(uriPref);
```